# Ruby send email with an attachment with /usr/sbin/sendmail

Tags: ruby, attachment, sendmail

I am trying to send an email with a csv file for attachement.
I do the following but I only receive an email with a empty csv file (and not with the content of it). Can you please help me on that?
I don't want to use any extra library so please don't tell me to use pony or so ;-)

```
to="me@exemple.com"
subject='The subject'
from='"Name" <you@exemple.com>'
description ="Desc"

csvnamefile = "/path/to/file/filename.csv"

puts  value = %x[/usr/sbin/sendmail #{to} << EOF
subject: #{subject}
from: #{from}
Content-Description: "#{csvnamefile}"
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; name="#{csvnamefile}"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="#{csvnamefile}"
Description : #{description}
EOF]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/sbin/sendmail` doesn't know anything about attachments and treats email message body according to [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2) as flat US-ASCII text. To send a file as attachment you need to format your message as MIME message according to [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045). For example of such a message see [Appendix A to RFC 2049](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2049#appendix-A).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Alex. I could make it work with your informations.
The final working result looks like this:

```
binary = File.read(csvnamefile)
encoded = [binary].pack("m")    # base64 econding
puts  value = %x[/usr/sbin/sendmail #{to} << EOF
subject: #{subject}
from: #{from}
Content-Description: "#{csvnamefile}"
Content-Type: text/csv; name="#{csvnamefile}"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="#{csvnamefile}"
#{encoded}
EOF]
```