# Send a mail using 'sendmail' with uuencode, and having a subject alongwith

Tags: linux, sendmail, uuencode

I am trying to send a mail with attachment using sendmail. The problem is I am unable to send a subject line along with this.

The following command line fires two mails instead of one - one with the "`Subject : Report`", and the other with the attachment:

```
/usr/bin/gmime-uuencode "/tmp/url_by_ip.txt" "Report.txt" | echo "Subject: Report" | /usr/sbin/sendmail <sender> <receiver>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you can use other commands, I'd suggest `mutt` which can handle attachments quite easily:

```
mutt -a file_to_attach -s "your subject" recipient@test.com < /tmp/mail_content
```

If you're stuck with `/usr/sbin/sendmail` then you have a lot more to do. `sendmail` has no concept of attachments and treats email content as a flat US-ASCII text (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732596/ruby-send-email-with-an-attachment-with-usr-sbin-sendmail/6735789#6735789) for details).

To send attachents with `sendmail` you'll need to format your  mail content as a MIME message. For some examples, see [this forum thread on unix.com](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/118534-sendmail-attachments.html).

---

To get you on your way, here's a quick **untested** example using bash. For brevity, I've hardcoded the variables but you can quite easily convert the example to a script/function that takes the relevant vars as arguments.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# --- user params ---
MAILFROM="peter.gibbons@initech.com"
MAILTO="bill.lumbergh@initech.com"
SUBJECT="TPS Report"
BODY_FILE="/home/peter/coversheey.txt"  # file holding mail body
ATT_FILE="/tnp/url_by_ip.txt"   # file to attach
ATT_AS_FILE="Report.txt"   # name to attach as

# --- generated values ---
BOUNDARY="unique-boundary-$RANDOM"
BODY_MIMETYPE=$(file -ib $BODY_FILE | cut -d";" -f1)   # detect mime type
ATT_MIMETYPE=$(file -ib $ATT_FILE | cut -d";" -f1)     # detect mime type
ATT_ENCODED=$(base64 < $ATT_FILE)  # encode attachment

# --- generate MIME message and pipe to sendmail ---
cat <<EOF | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: $MAILFROM
To: $MAILTO
Subject: $SUBJECT
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="$BOUNDARY"

--$BOUNDARY
Content-Type: $BODY_MIMETYPE
Content-Disposition: inline

$(cat $BODY_FILE)
--$BOUNDARY
Content-Type: $ATT_MIMETYPE; name="$ATT_AS_FILE"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$ATT_AS_FILE"

$ATT_ENCODED
--$BOUNDARY
EOF
```

Of course, if you're happy to use a higher level scripting language (Python, Ruby, Perl, ...) then there will be exisiting modules that will already do the heavy lifting for you.

p.s. There's also the [mpack](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpack) utility which does the MIME conversion for you, but AFAIK it doesn't come by default on most *nix boxes.

Comment: Mutt 1.5.20 on ubuntu 10.04 only works if I rearrange the command line parameters like so: `mutt -s "your subject" -a file_to_attach  -- recipient@test.com < /tmp/mail_content`

Comment: The base script works fine for me, and through a bit of modularization using functions and it is even elegant. I recommend using this in your scripts than installing mutt.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file with your mail header like for example mail.txt:

```
Subject: here is the subject
```

Here the script to send the email:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat mail.txt > mail_to_send
cat attachment | uuencode attachment >> mail_to_send
sendmail recipient@example.com < mail_to_send
rm mail_to_send
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`mail -s 'Report' myemail@yahoo.com < tmp/url_by_ip.txt`

Comment: Have to use sendmail and not mail.

Comment: Why? I thought both of them don't have too many differences. CMIIW.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want some utilities to send [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) mail? There is the [vmime C++ library](http://www.vmime.org/), many scripting languages (Python, Ruby, Perl, Ocaml, ...) have packages for MIME. There are also commands usable by shell scripts e.g. [mpack](ftp://ftp.andrew.cmu.edu/pub/mpack/) and many many others.